# JQuery DataTables - Personalizar Cabeçalho

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Pesquisei bastante e não consegui descobrir como personalizar o cabeçalho do relatório em pdf que gero a partir do plugin; Por exemplo, o "sTitle": "Grupos" é o título que fica no cabeçalho, porém ele sai com a estilização default do plugin, e também não sei como adicionar um subtítulo com seu próprio estilo, centralizar, adicionar uma data, etc.

Segue a chamada da tabela:

```
$("#dinamicTable").dataTable({
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "webroot/libs/datatables/js/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [ 
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sTitle": "Grupos"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sTitle": "Grupos"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

E a Tabela:

```
<table id="dinamicTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="10%">ID</th>
            <th>GRUPO</th>
            <th width="10%">STATUS</th>
            <th width="10%">OPÇÕES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($view_grupos as $grupo) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $grupo['grup_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $grupo['grup_nome']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $grupo['grup_status']; ?></td>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>GRUPO</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>OPÇÕES</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Só por desencargo de consciência mesmo, vc já tentou:`<th align="center" width="10%">ID</th>` se é isso que eu entendi?!

Comment: Não, não é o thead não. É o cabeçalho do relatório mesmo. Por exemplo, o `"sTitle": "Grupos"` é o título, porém ele sai com a estilização default do plugin, e também não sei como adicionar um subtítulo com seu próprio estilo, etc...

Comment: @LeoFelipe, tenho uma pergunta parecida com a sua. Por favor, veja este link, será que pode me ajudar?  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52567/exibir-elemento-search-do-jquery-datatables-em-uma-div-espec%C3%ADfica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, já bati muito a cabeça com esse problema. Eu li numa pergunta no [fórum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4498/table-tools-pdf-add-style-at-least-bold-and-italic/p1) e, segundo o próprio criador da funcionalidade Allan Jardine, não há como estilizar o "sTitle". Ele não aceita nem barras, hífen ou certos caracteres especiais. O autor disse que está desenvolvendo novas soluções e busca uma melhor API.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
var table = $('#dinamicTable').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
initComplete: function () {
            $('div.fg-toolbar:first').append('<span>Titulo</span>');
        }
```

.......